# Why can't I set ng-style to a node?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to set an ng-style:

javascript:

```
$offset='top:'+info.scrollTop+'px';
$scope.scrollTop = $offset;
console.log($scope);
```

markup:

```
    <div ng-controller="Legal" ng-style="scrollTop" class="footer">
```

the scope on console.log contains a node called scrollTop with the value `"top:0px"`

Comment: Doesn't `scrollTop` need to be an object, e.g. `{top: '0px'}`?

Comment: <div ng-controller="Legal" ng-style="scrollTop" class="footer">{{scrollTop}}</div>doesn't work either.

Comment: Like it doesn't show up in the div?  Try setting `scrollTop = {top: '0px'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (color works, but top I'm not sure):

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('App', []);

function Legal($scope) {
  var offset = {color:'red', top: '100px'};
  $scope.scrollTop = offset;
  console.log($scope.scrollTop);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Legal" ng-style="scrollTop" class="footer">Test {{scrollTop}}</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdSbCU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The `ngStyle` directive accepts an object with style names as keys, not a string:

```
$offset= info.scrollTop+'px';
$scope.scrollTop = {top: $offset};
```

Then your markup will work:

```
<div ng-controller="Legal" ng-style="scrollTop" class="footer">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiattp/y8WjA/6/)